# Purpose of using pass in example Python function

Tags: python, function, if-statement, tuples

I'm currently taking a Python course on Udemy and I'm at the point where I'm learning to create my own functions.  In the section dealing with functions and tuple unpacking, I was shown the example function:

def employee_check(work_hours):

```
current_max = 0
employee_of_month = ''

for employee,hours in work_hours:
    if hours > current_max:
      current_max = hours
      employee_of_month = employee
    else:
      pass

#Return
return(employee_of_month,current_max)
```

My question is simply what is the point of putting pass as an else statement in this specific example?  Messing around, it seems to still operate properly whenever I take it out, is there a use that I'm not aware of or is it just a good habit to get into when creating functions?

EDIT: The purpose of the function being to designate the employee of the month based on total hours worked

Comment: There's no point in doing it functionally, but some may argue that it adds to the readability.

Answer (score 3):

Good habit, easier readability, faster to understand. And it means that you deliberately wanted to skip doing something on the `else` condition.

Alternatively, you could consider (or someone who is reading your code) that you missed / ignored what would happen in the `else` condition.

A good practice is to think what would future you / other person would think when they see your code. Also, most courses encourage these good practices.